# JSON (using jsonlite) parsing error in R

Tags: json, r, dataframe, jsonlite

I have the following JSON file:

```
{"id":1140854908,"name":"'Amran"} 
{"id":1140852651,"name":"'Asir"} 
{"id":1140855190,"name":"'Eua"} 
{"id":1140851307,"name":"A Coruna"} 
{"id":1140854170,"name":"A`Ana"}
```

I used the package jsonlite but I get a parsing error

```
library(jsonlite) 
try <- fromJSON("states.txt",simplifyDataFrame = T)
# Error in feed_push_parser(readBin(con, raw(), n), reset = TRUE) :   
# parse error: trailing garbage
#           :1140854908,"name":"'Amran"} {"id":1140852651,"name":"'Asir"
#                      (right here) ------^
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing your data file to below

```
[
{"id":1140854908,"name":"'Amran"} 
,{"id":1140852651,"name":"'Asir"} 
,{"id":1140855190,"name":"'Eua"} 
,{"id":1140851307,"name":"A Coruna"} 
,{"id":1140854170,"name":"A`Ana"}
]
```

The same code worked for me.. It is looking for an array..

Comment: This solution has solved the same problem for me on two completely separate occasions, first with Twitter JSON data and secondly with Reddit JSON data.

Comment: While this answer was accepted as the correct one, I don't think that this answer will generally solve the problem. Under most circumstances, the user won't be able to manually change the json file.

Answer (score 2):

Your file is a newline delimited JSON (http://ndjson.org/). You can read it with jsonlite like this:

```
try <- stream_in(file("states.txt"))
```